# Need help running two OS containers in a single pod on kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, vnc

I'm still new to Kubernetes. I'm trying to run a ubuntu container and a linux kali container within the same pod on kubernetes. I also need those two containers to be able to be accessed from a browser. My approach right now is using ubuntu and kali docker image with VNC installed.

Here are the docker image that I'm trying to use:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/consol/ubuntu-xfce-vnc (Ubuntu image)
- https://hub.docker.com/r/jgamblin/kalibrowser-lxde (Kali image)

Here is the YAML file for creating the pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: training
  labels:
    app: training
spec:
  containers:
    - name: kali
      image: jgamblin/kalibrowser-lxde
      ports:
        - containerPort: 6080
    - name: centos
      image: consol/centos-xfce-vnc
      ports:
        - containerPort: 5901
```

Here's the problem. When I run the pod with those 2 containers, only the Kali container is having issue running, cause it to keep on restarting.

May I know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Why is it restarting; what do the container logs say?  Is the second container important to the problem (does the first container start without it)?

Comment: When I check the kali container using `kubectl logs training kali` it just returns `User: ubuntu Pass: ubuntu`. When I run `kubectl describe pod training`, it shows `Warning  BackOff    2s (x3 over 20s)  kubelet, k8s-worker2  Back-off restarting failed container`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a simple sleep command to be executed inside then container to keep it running, for example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: training
  labels:
    app: training
spec:
  containers:
    - name: kali
      image: jgamblin/kalibrowser-lxde
      ports:
        - containerPort: 6080
      command: ["bash", "-c"]
      args: ["sleep 500"]
    - name: centos
      image: consol/centos-xfce-vnc
      ports:
        - containerPort: 5901`
```

This way the pod will be in `running` state:

```
kubectl get pod
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
training                        2/2     Running   0          81s
```

Comment: Thanks, adding sleep command stops the container from restarting. I can enter into the container's shell using `kubectl exec`.

Answer (score 0):

jgamblin/kalibrowser-lxde image require tty (display) allocation.

You can see an example command on docker hub page.

Then you should allow it in your Pod manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: training
  labels:
    app: training
spec:
  containers:
    - name: kali
      image: jgamblin/kalibrowser-lxde
      ports:
        - containerPort: 6080
      tty: true
    - name: centos
      image: consol/centos-xfce-vnc
      ports:
        - containerPort: 5901
```

Put `tty: true` in kali container declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I added `tty: true` but the issue still persist.

Comment: You should delete Pod and recreate it. On my 1.15.5 I was deleted by kubectl delete and create from scratch...